# SQL Server connection settings when using freetds from PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, freetds

I'm connecting to SQL server from Linux environment using PHP with help of FreeTDS library. And looks like some connection parameters are being explicitly turned off. Specifically, somewhere in the process these are being ran:

```
set quoted_identifier off
set ansi_warnings off
set ansi_padding off
set ansi_nulls off
set concat_null_yields_null off
```

How can I adjust connection parameters globally (either on PHP level or on FreeTDS level) to set all of the above to ON, without having to change any of the applications on the server in any way?

**EDIT:**

Tried suggestion with odbc.ini, does not seem to work.

Here's my freetds.conf:

```
[Servername]
host = hostname.example.com
port = 1433
tds version = 7.0
timeout 3600    client charset UTF-8    text size 64512
```

odbc.ini:

```
AnsiNPW = YES
QuotedID = YES
```

odbcinst.ini is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these settings to your `odbc.ini` file in your server DSN (rather than freetds.conf):

```
[myserver]
... my server settings ...
AnsiNPW = NO
QuotedID = NO
```

You can see more of the settings you can change here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms811006.aspx

Good luck!

Comment: That's for Windows environment. Sorry, I didn't include this detail in my original post, but adjusted now to clarify that I'm connecting from within Linux.

Comment: Actually, that's from Linux. FreeTDS + unixODBC work together to connect to SQL Server. Your odbc.ini will most likely be in /etc/odbc.ini. Give it a try?

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. Tried this, and did not help. Plus, `concat_null_yields_null` is not mentioned in the doc, and it's one of those that lead to problems by itself.

Comment: Can you amend your question to include the contents of freetds.conf, odbc.ini and odbcinst.ini? They are most often all kept in `/etc`.